# memcpy from Byte * to unsigned int Is Reversing Byte Order

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory, endianness, memcpy

I have a `CFBitVector` that looks like `'100000000000000'`
I pass the byte array to `CFBitVectorGetBits`, which then contains the values from this `CFBitVector`. After this call, `bytes[2]` looks like:

```
bytes[0] == '0x80'
bytes[1] == '0x00'
```

This is exactly what I would expect. However, when copying the contents of `bytes[2]` to `unsigned int bytesValue,` the value is `128` when it should be `32768`. The decimal value `128` is represented by the hex value `0x0080`. Essentially it seems that the byte order is reversed while performing `memcpy`. What is going on here? Is this just an issue with endianness?

Thanks

```
CFMutableBitVectorRef bitVector = CFBitVectorCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 16);
CFBitVectorSetCount(bitVector, 16);

CFBitVectorSetBitAtIndex(bitVector, 0, 1);

CFRange range = CFRangeMake(0, 16);
Byte bytes[2] = {0,0};
unsigned int bytesValue = 0;

CFBitVectorGetBits(bitVector, range, bytes);
memcpy(&bytesValue, bytes, sizeof(bytes));

return bytesValue;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here? Is this just an issue with endianness?

Yes.

Your computer is little endian.  The 16-bit value `32768` would be represented in-memory as:

```
00 80
```

On a little endian machine.  You have:

```
80 00
```

Which is the opposite, representing 128 as you're seeing.

Comment: Should I be testing for the endianness of the machine prior to making a decision on how to handle the byte values? That doesn't seem like a fair solution.

Comment: Well, you can push the testing off to the system by using an `ntohs` or `ntohl` call in there, if you want.  What do you mean by "fair"?

Comment: On the Mac and iOS platform there is also `OSSwapLittleToHostInt16()` and related methods.

Comment: If want to directly deal with the bytes that make up an `int` then you are going to have to deal with endian issues. You can complain about "fairness", but it's just the nature of the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the responses, everyone. `htons` seems to be a good fit for this.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should use `ntohs`.  They're the same, though.